# Dead-letter in Akka Scala actors

Tags: scala, akka, actor, dead-letter

I have a very simple structure based on Akka actors in Scala, but I keep on receiving warnings about undelivered messages. This is the code for the main class, Collector is a separate class extending Actor:

```
object Executor extends App {

  class ExecutorMaster extends Actor {

    def receive() = {
      case _ => Executor.actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Collector], name = "Collector") ! true
    }

  }

  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("ReadScheduler")
  private val app = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[ExecutorMaster], name = "Executor")

  app ! true

}
```

The message is not being delivered to the Collector, the result for the code is:

> [04/27/2014 18:09:05.518]
>   [ReadScheduler-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3]
>   [akka://ReadScheduler/user/Collector] Message [java.lang.Boolean] from
>   Actor[akka://ReadScheduler/user/Executor#2127791644] to
>   Actor[akka://ReadScheduler/user/Collector#337715308] was not
>   delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned
>   off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters'
>   and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.

What can be the reason of this unsuccessful delivery of the message? Is there something that I keep on missing in the concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a hierarchy - launch that `Collector` as a child of the `ExecutorMaster`.

What you are doing inside the `receive` method is attempting to create an actor having the same name as another one that gets created after the first message that the `ExecutorMaster` receives.

Consider using:

```
val collector = context.actorOf(Props[Collector], name = "Collector")
def receive = {
    case _ => collector ! true
}
```

You also ought to use a `case object` and not a primitive to identify the meaning of `true`.