# Akka sender reference contains dead letters

Tags: scala, akka

```
object SenderTest extends App {
  val s = ActorSystem("test")
  val ar = s.actorOf(Props[A], "Aactor")
  ar ! "abc"
}

class A extends Actor {
  val sender_ = sender()
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _: String => {
      println("inside A receive block")
      val b = context.actorOf(Props[B], "Bactor")
      b ! 12
    }
  }
}

class B extends Actor {
  val sender_ = sender()
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _: Int => {
      println(sender_)
      println("inside B receive block")
      sender_ ! 22
    }
  }
}
```

I was expecting `println(sender_)` to print actor `A` information, but it's printing dead letters. As it's called from actor `A`, I don't understand why it's printing dead letters. How do I modify this so that I can get the sender's reference?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23327675/1531971

Comment: @jdv, not at all linked to it, in A it will be deadletter as its called from main App but in B it shouldn't be deadletters, that is my question

Comment: It is related in terms of research. Your message could not be delivered, even after best effort. So this is where you have to start. Not too many people are going to debug this for you, so your chances of an actual answer go up if you show what steps you took to debug and research this.

Comment: @jdv, println is the debugging point for your information, I am guessing if U had enough akka knowledge then u might have answered instead of criticising..

Comment: Oh, well. If you used a few println lines that don't do much than illustrate that the code is being reached than I guess you did everything humanly possible. Every question on this site is open for criticism in order to make it better. You are very welcome! Ironically, the link I gave had a hint for the exact answer given here. Have a super nice day, and welcome to the site.

Comment: I am not new to the site, I been using for past 5 years with different accounts, I just accepted the answer, he had the knowledge he answered, u had nothing u criticized.

Comment: Oh stop moaning and complaining. It isn't my problem you can't stick to a single account. (Which is why this was flagged as a new question from a new user, and everyone asked to help make it better.) The whole point of this site is to "criticize" to make the Q&A as best as it can. If you've been here for so long, you'd know this already.

Comment: I like sticking to multiple accounts, whatz ur problem with that,I've seen people with no answers to asked questions just editing and complaining like, do this or do that, just like u,people like u  will just roam around criticising and complaining.

Comment: I didn't say I had a problem with multiple accounts. This is **technically** a new posting from a new user. It gets attention. It is _supposed_ to get attention. You are overreacting; so calm down and expect people to react to, offer advice, edit, and otherwise challenge your questions and answers. This is how SO works. Your question belongs to everyone, and everyone will criticize it as much as necessary.

Comment: FYI, here is the general policy about multiple accounts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts The take-away: "Multiple accounts are gently discouraged without enforcement (or perhaps with gentle, human moderated enforcement from the team)." It also begs the question, why would you do such a thing? What benefit does it give you or others? This is a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the sender inside the `receive` method:

```
class B extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _: Int =>
      val sender_ = sender()
      println(sender_)
      println("inside B receive block")
      sender_ ! 22
  }
}
```

Note that actor `A` in its current state doesn't handle an `Int` (which is what `B` is sending to `A`).